# Create Birthday List

Tags: list-view

I have a custom list used as a personnel database, one field of which is date of birth.  How can I create a calendar view which returns the birthday in the current year from the date of birth field?

Comment: Why not just create a calendar?

Comment: Because the entry will show only in the year of birth, not in the current year.  I need some sort of calculation to apply to the date of birth to bring it to the current year, then create a calendar displaying that value.

Comment: Could you put more details (perhaps some sample data and output expected) in your question please as I am not sure what outputs you are expecting.   You can create calculated column the calendar app and retrieve Year.

Comment: I have design rights to the site group for my organization, but I am not a server admin.  In the site group I have a custom list used as a personnel data base which contain administrative information, one field of which is the date of birth in a date field.  What I'm trying to do is create a view of that custom list, preferably a calendar view, which will show upcoming birthdays based on the date of birth field.  If you create a calendar view of the date of birth field those entries are returned across the entire span of birth years, so that doesn't work.

Comment: What I need is something that returns the correct birth day and month, but inside the current year, to make this useful as a birthday reminder tool.

Answer (score 1):

A simple no code solution is to create the calendar items using the existing dates and make the items **all day events** and **recurring every year**.

Comment: Can you tell us the format of the data source, how many items, what type of access you have to the farm, any desired methods? Can't really know what type of solution to suggest without more information.